# Vuex actions and dialog window

Tags: vue.js, vuex

My application has a function to save a document, which opens a save dialog to let the user choose where to save the document.

Since that function handles not only state but also a part of the UI/UX through the use of a dialog, is it considered a bad practice to move that piece of code in a `saveDocument` Vuex action, so that it would be reusable from multiple places in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's a bad pratice. Actions can receive parameters and they usually do.

Anyway, you can store the variable which says where to save the document in your state (setting a default value if you want) and change the value (with an action and a mutation) in your UI/UX component. Then in your action, you can get this information from the state via getter.

I hope this helps!